# APIM (4.0, 4.1) How to configure apim to retry after receive http/500 with soapfault

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, apim

I have two endpoints: main and failover. When apim sends request to main endpoint, it returns http/500 with  SoapFault next apim processes the error and starts prepare request to second(faiover)  endpoint and  hangs on  class XFormURLEncodedBuilder  (code line:  String line = bufferedReader.readLine).

Is there a possibility to configure apim to retry (de facto failover) when it receives http/500 with  SoapFault from the first endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no global configuration as such to enable endpoint failover.

Comment: Thanks,  What you mean global configuration.  I have one api  with two backend endpoint (main and second - which should work as failover but not working). My question is, apim in this configuration work as designed or it is my configuration mistake

Comment: @andpel failover should work as expected. I can't really say what's going on with the provided information.

Comment: Could you help, request should be http post? (or is no matter)

Comment: @andpel can you add the full error logs? SOAP Request has to be POST requests.